# Copy integers from a file to another in C

Tags: c

I want to copy files from a file to another, without scanning them, storing them into an array and printing them. I would like to copy directly.

So, for doing that I've written this code. But I'm not able to copy the integers to the file. I need to do the next operations.

```
First number=first number
Second number=first number+second number
Third number=first number+second number+third number ...
```

And this is my code. I have `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` in `data.dat`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char number='0';
    char a;

    FILE *data;
    FILE *sum;

    data=fopen("data.dat", "rt");

    if (data==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    sum=fopen("sum.dat", "wt");

    if (sum==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((a=fgetc(data))!=EOF){
        number=number+a;
        putc(number,sum);
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

I should get `1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45` in `sum.dat`.

```
1=1
3=2+1
6=3+2+1
10=4+3+2+1
15=5+4+3+2+1
21=6+5+4+3+2+1
28=7+6+5+4+3+2+1
36=8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1
45=9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1
```

Comment: `fgetc` reads a raw byte. To read numbers use `fscanf`

Comment: @user1320881 if I use `fscanf` gives me error too.

Comment: Of course this implies you make the same mistake for writing. use `fprintf`in stead of `putc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int number=0;
    int a;

    FILE *data;
    FILE *sum;

    data=fopen("data.dat", "rt");

    if (data==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    sum=fopen("sum.dat", "wt");

    if (sum==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(data, "%d ", &a) != EOF)
    {
        number += a;
        fprintf(sum, "%d ", number);
    }


    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char number='0';
    char a;

    FILE *data;
    FILE *sum;

    data=fopen("data.dat", "rt");

    if (data==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    sum=fopen("sum.dat", "wt");

    if (sum==NULL){
        printf("Error abriendo fichero ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((fscanf(data," %d",a))!=EOF){
        number=number+a;
        fprintf(sum,"%d",number);
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: `number` and `a` must be `int` to match `%d`.